# LISP Sum of list items

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I wrote this macro that rewrites e.g. `(sum-expr (1 2 3))` as `(+ 1 2 3)`:

```
(defmacro sum-expr (expr-list)
  `(+ ,@expr-list))

=> SUM-EXPR
```

For example:

```
(sum-expr ((+ 1 3) (* 3 4) (- 8 4)))

=> 20
```

How can I define an equivalent function using `defun`?

Comment: Do you want the function to take as inputs *expressions* or a list of numbers to add?

Comment: `(reduce #'+ ...)` is what you want.  There is no purpose in having this be a macro.

Comment: this needs a bit more info for a complete answer - do you need to pass it as a quoted list? Since you can't pass `((+ 1 3) (* 3 4) (- 8 4))` as an argument to a function. You need to pass either `'((+ 1 3) (* 3 4) (- 8 4))` or `(list (+ 1 3) (* 3 4) (- 8 4))`. The first one needs a more complex solution; the latter is simpler

Answer (score 2):

As @LeonardoDagnino already mentioned it in comment:

```
(defun sum-expr (lst)
  (apply #'+ lst))
```

Would be very lispy, but implementation-dependent `CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT` limits in some implementations the length of `lst` to 50 as discussed e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48103575/9690090) .Therefore, the solution with `reduce` is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to evaluate the expressions in your list, and then reduce the resulting list by the addition function.

We can evaluate lisp expressions with `eval`, which we can apply to each element of the input list with `mapcar`.

We can then use `reduce` on the resulting list to find the sum.

```
(defun sum-expr (list)
  (reduce #'+ (mapcar #'eval list)))
```

This makes a lot of assumptions about the structure and type of your input, but for a simple problem with well-understood inputs, it should be fine.

(You may be interested in [Why exactly is eval evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil))

Comment: Could also use `apply` instead of `reduce` since `+` already accepts multiple arguments.

Comment: You don't need `eval` if you just rely on normal evaluation order, and `reduce` is what you use for arbitrary lists.  `Apply` is for argument management, not for shoehorning data into rest arguments.

Comment: @Svante If the input specification is more flexible than "a list of expressions", I agree. If, in fact, the requirements are a function that takes a list, I don't see another way. What am I missing?